# XSL repeat the parent node for each child node

Tags: xslt

For each child node, I want to duplicate my parent node so that the resulting xml, contains only one child for the parent node with the other nodes being the same.

Here is a sample input

```
<a>
  <a1>header1</a1>
  <a2>header2</a2>
  <a3>
     <a31>
          <a311>line_1</a311>
          <a311>line_2</a311>
     </a31>
     <a32>5o$</a32>
     <a33>Add</a33>
  </a3>
  <a4>account_holder</a4>
</a>
```

What I want to do is - repeat a3 for as many times as the node a311 comes. Rest all nodes are retained

Output

```
<a>
   <a1>header1</a1>
   <a2>header2</a2>
   <a3>
      <a31>
          <a311>line_1</a311>
      </a31>
      <a32>5o$</a32>
      <a33>Add</a33>
   </a3>
   <a3>
      <a31>
          <a311>line_2</a311>
      </a31>
      <a32>5o$</a32>
      <a33>Add</a33>
    </a3>
    <a4>account_holder</a4>
</a>
```

Comment: Did that originally look like XML when you typed it in?  Because it is not displaying as XML.

Comment: Do you only want to do this when your child elements have the same name? e.g. in your example the a311 elements. You've also copied the a3 element, which isn't the parent of the a311 elements. I think you need to be clearer about exactly which levels you want to apply this to, how far down the axes, and using which rules.

Answer (score 2):

More semantic with "tunnel param" pattern, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pCurrent"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="pCurrent" select="$pCurrent"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a3">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="vDescendants" select=".//a311"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$vDescendants|$vCurrent[not($vDescendants)]">
            <xsl:variable name="vDescendant" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCurrent">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pCurrent" select="$vDescendant"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a311">
        <xsl:param name="pCurrent"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id($pCurrent)">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<a>
    <a1>header1</a1>
    <a2>header2</a2>
    <a3>
        <a31>
            <a311>line_1</a311>
        </a31>
        <a32>5o$</a32>
        <a33>Add</a33>
    </a3>
    <a3>
        <a31>
            <a311>line_2</a311>
        </a31>
        <a32>5o$</a32>
        <a33>Add</a33>
    </a3>
    <a4>account_holder</a4>
</a>
```

**EDIT**: Handling no descendants case.

Comment: I have tried this for a similar case and it works, but it produces too many linebreaks in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The following (XSLT 1.0) stylesheet produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a3">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a31/a311" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a311">
        <a3>
            <a31>
                <a311>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </a311>
            </a31>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../../*[not(self::a31)]" />
        </a3>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the XSLT version.  Here's an XSLT2 stylesheet that will accomplish what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a3" mode="#default">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a31/a311"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a311">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../.." mode="x">
      <xsl:with-param name="label" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a3" mode="x">
    <xsl:param name="label"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <a31>
        <a311><xsl:value-of select="$label"/></a311>
      </a31>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* except a31"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses an identity transform to pass through the "uninteresting" elements while trapping the `<a3>` node and applying special handling.  If you need an XSLT1 solution, merely

- Replace `select="* except a31"` with `select="*[name() != 'a31']"`
- Remove the `mode="#default"` in the first "a3" template